# Programmatically setting the PaperItem label of a core-dropdown element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following core-elements dropdown element in which I used paper-item instead of core-item to display the dropdown label.

// .html

```dart
  <input required
    id='birthday'
    name='birthday'
    type='date'
    value="{{age.birthday}}"
    on-change='{{inputHandler}}'>

<div layout horizontal>
  <div layout vertical self-center
    id='years-div'>Years
    <core-dropdown  disabled
      id='years-core-ddwn'
      halign="left"
      label='0'
      valueattr="label">
      <template repeat="{{year in yearsList}}">
        <paper-item id='years-ppr-itm' label="{{year}}"></paper-item>
      </template>
    </core-dropdown>
  </div>
```

//.dart

```dart
var yearsList = <int>[ 1, 2, 3, 4]
@observable int year = 0;

class Age
{
  int years = 0;
  String birthday = '';     
} 


// calcualate age in years
      void inputHandler()
      {
        if ( age.birthday != '' )
        {
          DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
          DateTime birthday = DateTime.parse( age.birthday.replaceAll( r'-', '') );

          //Duration dayz = ( birthday.difference( new DateTime.now() ) ).inDays;
          Duration duration = new DateTime.now().difference( birthday );

          // calculate years since birth
          int days = duration.inDays;
          age.years = days ~/ 365;

      // attempting to set the PaperItem label to the calculated age
          yearsPprItm = $[ 'years-ppr-itm' ] as PaperItem;

          // neither of the following resets the PaperItem label to the age variable
          yearsPprItm.setAttribute( 'label', age.years.toString() );
          //year = age.years.toString();
    }
```

The drop-down displays normally and selected item is retrieved normally also.
There are no error stack trace, yet the paper-item label is not changed using setAttribute or assigning the age.years to the observable year to which the label is bound.

I am wondering if it is illegal to bind to and iterator variable. If so, what is the correct method of accomplishing what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as far as I know, expect the year

```dart
<template repeat="{{year in yearList}}">
```

to be a binding to

```dart
@observable int year;
```

As I think year in the template is a locally created variable, with nothing to do with the observable year you created in the backing class.  I'd have to look up the documentation though, for a better explanation.

The only way to get the template to bind to year is to change

```dart
<template repeat="{{year in yearList}}">
    <paper-item label="{{year}}"></paper-item>
</template>
```

to

```dart
<template repeat="{{id in yearList}}">
    <paper-item label="{{year}}"></paper-item>
</template>
```

The problem with that is, when year is updated, it will update to the same value in each  displayed.  What I think you want is something like this

```dart
<template repeat="{{ year in yearList }}">
    <paper-item label="{{year.years}}"></paper-item>
</template>
```

with the backing yearList being

```dart
List<Age> yearList = [new Age(0), new Age(1), ...];
```

and Age being

```dart
class Age extends Observable {
    @observable int years;
    String birthday = '';

    Year(this.year);
}
```

Then you can update an item in the list and the change will be reflected in the display.  At least that's something like what I think you're after.  I'm sure there are other ways of doing this as well as what I suggest.  Unless I'm also not understanding what it is you're after.

Answer (score 0):

#### edit

```dart
    <core-dropdown  disabled
                    id='years-core-ddwn'
                    halign="left"
                    label='0'
                    valueattr="label" selected="{{age.years}}"> <!-- added `selected` attribute -->
      <template repeat="{{year in yearsList}}">
        <paper-item label="{{year}}"></paper-item> <!-- don't add static id in <template repeat> -->
      </template>
    </core-dropdown>
```

make the Age class observable so the `<core-dropdown>` selection gets updated automatically.

```dart
class Age extends Observable {
  @observable
  int years = 0;
  String birthday = '';
}
```

#### old answer

This can't work:

```dart
  <template repeat="{{year in yearsList}}">
    <!-- for each item in yearsList a paper-item with the id 'years-ppr-itm' is created
         but 'id' is supposed to be unique. -->
    <paper-item id='years-ppr-itm' label="{{year}}"></paper-item>
  </template>
```

You just need to modify the `yearsList` list to contain the year values you want and the items update automatically.

What you need to change in your code to make it work:

change

```dart
var yearsList = <int>[ 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

to

```dart
var yearsList = toObservable(<int>[ 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

`toObservable()` notifies Polymer about added/removed list items.
If you assign another list to `yearsList` instead of adding removing values you need to do it like

```dart
// declaration/initialization
@observable
var yearsList = toObservable(<int>[ 1, 2, 3, 4]);

...

// later assignment of a new list
yearsList = toObservable(<int>[ 5, 6, 7, 8]);
```

If you don't modify the list elements and always assign a new list to `yearsList` you can omit `toObservable()` but not `@observable`

Comment: It is not so much as displaying a new list or removing or adding to the list, but rather selecting the list item equivalent to the calculated age. So, if the age is caculated to be 4, I would like to display 4 in the list instead of the default 0 when the list is created.

Comment: The `<paper-item>`s are just the list to select from. the selected element is defined by the `selected` attribute of the `<core-dropdown>`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried the updated suggestion before I posted the question - it did not work. I tried again after your suggestion and it still did not work. I am wondering if the selected element is final and occurs only at initilization of the drop-down.

Comment: Maybe I still didn't understand what you want to accomplish.